# How can I stop vim from loading a syntax file automatically for certain file types?

Tags: vim

I am working on a project writing a GLSL fragment shader, and it just so happens it has the file extension `.fs`, thus vim automatically loads the forth syntax upon opening the file.

This normally would be no problem, I could just change the syntax using `au BufRead` but for some reason the forth syntax is loaded first, which completely messes things up. It adds more characters to a "word" which causes syntax highlighting and motions to not work as expected.

Is there a way to stop the forth syntax from loading, and only load my specified syntax?

Comment: If you manually do `:set syn=glsl`, does that work as desired?

Comment: nope, the damage has already been done after the file has loaded. I found the line that makes the change, I could just undo it but I would like to find a cleaner solution.

It is `set iskeyword` if you are interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file in your `.vim` directory (or `vimfiles` directory on Windows) called `filetype.vim` and put this code in it:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
    finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect

    " Ignore filetypes for *.fs files
    autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.fs  setfiletype ignored

augroup END
```

This places a custom filetype-detection script ahead of Vim's default filetype autocommands, so your detection autocommands get a chance to determine the filetype before the usual Vim scripts.

Once you restart Vim and attempt to load a `.fs` file, it should no longer use Forth syntax highlighting, and `iskeyword` should still be set to the default value. (If you've installed a syntax file for the GLSL fragment files, you can replace the `ignored` with the appropriate filetype name.)

See these topics for more info:

```
:help remove-filetype
:help new-filetype
:help :setfiletype
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the end of your syntax file:

```
let b:current_syntax = "<filetype>"
```