# How can ~/.vimrc overrule filetype.vim's bad guess for syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, glsl, vim-syntax-highlighting

The GLSL syntax highlighter http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1002 works well. But it doesn't recognize .frag or .vert shader files that commonly begin with a line like `#version 330`.  (This is on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, everything up to date.)

With such a line, after loading the file one must manually type `set syntax=glsl`,
probably because /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim has

`" Generic configuration file (check this last, it's just guessing!)`

`if` ... `getline(1)=~'^#'` ... `setf conf`.

Why doesn't that get overruled by ~/.vimrc's `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.frag,*.vert setf glsl`?  Is there a workaround short of blundering about in filetype.vim?

Answer (score 2):

[How can I stop vim from loading a syntax file automatically for certain file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286886/how-can-i-stop-vim-from-loading-a-syntax-file-automatically-for-certain-file-typ) came close.  Here's the workaround, a file ~/.vim/filetype.vim:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect
  " Override filetypes for certain files
  autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.frag setfiletype glsl
  autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.vert setfiletype glsl
augroup END
```